# Python can't recognize image spawned by Node.JS JSON Stdin write

Tags: javascript, python, node.js

I'm trying to pass an image from a Node.JS script to a Python script, then save it in the directory `assets/media/`.

The script `index.js` reads the image file, stores it in a JSON variable `params` and spawns a python script `script.py` to which it passes the JSON string.

Inside the python script, the image name `params['name']` reads just fine. However, the image data at `params['image']` isn't recognized as the right encoding.

I've tried decoding the image data using `base64.b64decode(params['image'],'UTF-8')`, however this gives me the error, `UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-1: ordinal not in range(128)`.

Could you please help me spot and fix the problem with this code?

Thanks in advance!

index.js:

```
const spawn = require("child_process").spawn;
const fs = require('fs');

let params = {
    "image":readDataset(),
    "name":"image.png"
  }

const pythonProcess = spawn('py',['script.py']);

pythonProcess.stdin.write(JSON.stringify(params) + '\n');

pythonProcess.stdout.on("data", (data) =>{
  console.log(data.toString());
});

function readDataset() {
    try { 
        return fs.readFileSync('color.png',  'binary');
    }
    catch (err) { 
        return err;
    }
}
```

script.py:

```
import sys, json

json_str = input() # Capture data input

params = json.loads(json_str) # Load parameters values (params)

# Import resources
import numpy as np
import cv2
import os

fileName = params['name'] # Capture file name
fileData = params['image'] # Capture file

# Convert Image to Numpy array
img = np.array(fileData)

# Save file to local directory
cv2.imwrite(os.path.join('assets/media/', f'{fileName}'), img)
cv2.waitKey(0)

print("File Saved!")
sys.stdout.flush()
```

Comment: You can't send binary data via JSON like that.  It has to be encoded in some way, either as a list of integers, or converted to hex, or base64.  Base64 decoding will work if you base64 encode on the Javascript side.  Although, if this is a direct process call, there's not much point in using JSON at all.  Just send the name and a newline, then the image data.  You can search for the newline in your Python and split it into the two parts.

Comment: I wonder why you want to pass an image data from Node.JS to Python.
Is there a restriction preventing you from using only Node.JS objects, or using Python objects only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change 'binary' file encoding to 'base64' inside 'index.js' and decode it using base64 inside 'script.py'.
Then parse image data to numpy array.

index.js:

```js
const spawn = require("child_process").spawn;
const fs = require('fs');

let params = {
    "image":readDataset(),
    "name":"image.png"
  }

const pythonProcess = spawn('py',['script.py']);

pythonProcess.stdin.write(JSON.stringify(params) + '\n');

pythonProcess.stdout.on("data", (data) =>{
  console.log(data.toString());
});

function readDataset() {
    try { 
        return fs.readFileSync('color.png',  'base64');
    }
    catch (err) { 
        return err;
    }
}
```

script.py:

```py
import sys, json

json_str = input() # Capture data input

params = json.loads(json_str) # Load parameters values (params)

# Import resources
import numpy as np
import cv2
import os
import base64

fileName = params['name'] # Capture file name
fileData = base64.b64decode(params['image']) # Capture file

# Parse image data to Numpy array
img_buffer = np.frombuffer(fileData, dtype=np.uint8)
img = cv2.imdecode(img_buffer, flags=1)

# Save file to local directory
cv2.imwrite(os.path.join('assets/media/', f'{fileName}'), img)
cv2.waitKey(0)

print("File Saved!")
sys.stdout.flush()
```